# Is installing node js in an ubuntu client the same as isntall it as a server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server

I have to configurate a server running "Apache2 Ubuntu". I have found this page: https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/install-mean-stack-ubuntu16/. If you have experience with ubuntu as server, can you tell if the process of using ubuntu as development and server is the same? would you consider the instructions pointed out therein the same? best regards, Jorge,

Answer (score 0):

it would be generally the same as running a server. To make it forward-facing you would need to forward the port of the Node JS site on your router. HOWEVER, it is not recommended to host using a node js site. Node JS is still used on live sites for the purpose of automating tasks but it is not recommended for hosting. Apache2 is recommended for hosting a site and here is a link for getting it started https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-apache2-virtual-hosting-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

Comment: Dear Thomas Braccia, thanks for the reply. I have already configured the Apache2, now I need to use it to run a nodejs application. I already have the link, active, for a page we want to configurate. I already have a simple nodejs application and we want to make the link show the application. I am not sure if I was clear on my questioning.

Comment: Regarding “To make it forward-facing you would need to forward the port of the Node JS site on your router.” Since I want to get something initial for test reasons. Can you explain better this approach, even if it is not the most appropriate ones? Thanks in advance!